# Rebuild/Reorganize is not working for some tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am re-building/re-organizing my index using this blog http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858(v=sql.110).aspx. For most of time its working except few cases. For example,

```
SELECT
    dbschemas.[Name] AS 'Schema',
    dbtables.[Name] AS 'Table',
    dbindexes.[Name] AS 'Index',
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.TABLES dbtables
    ON dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas
    ON dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes
    ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

Will shows me this result.

```
Schema  Table                   Index                           avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbo     DealGallery             NULL                                83.3333333333333                7
dbo     UserRewardActions       NULL                                77.2034742987327                56153
dbo     Order                   PK__Order__3214EC275CFA57FE         50                              2
dbo     RetailersTranslations   PK__Retailer__3214EC2736153FBA      50                              2
dbo     Batch                   PK__Batch__3214EC2786046795         50                              2
dbo     BatchProducts           PK__BatchPro__3214EC2709FBECDC      50                              2
dbo     ProductDeals            PK__ProductD__3214EC27CE27FF86      50                              2
dbo     PopTemplates            PK__PopTempl__3214EC279BBD3055      21.0526315789474                19
dbo     ELMAH_Error             NULL                                10.3310852237891                52113
```

Rebuilding for the above indexes is not working. I am using,

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON DealGallery  
REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,
              STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON);

ALTER INDEX ALL ON DealGallery  
REORGANIZE ;
```

Also can someone explain why it showing me NULL in Index column?

Comment: How big are these tables? For smaller tables it simply isn't going to do anything. Also why a rebuild *and* a reorganize?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Thanks.  Rebuild for >30% and reorganize is for 5-30%. UserRewardActions is big. See page_count above

Comment: And is UserRewardActions a heap? Why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, what do you mean?

Comment: Does UserRewardActions not have a clustered index?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Thanks. You are right. I forgot to add Primary Key in this table. Adding it fixed my fragmentation issue in UserRewardActions table. Thanks. What about other tables?

Comment: Most of them are too small. Why on earth are you even *looking* at tables with 2 pages? Go get [Ola's scripts](http://ola.hallengren.com) and stop worrying about this. Also be sure to [read this](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, is there is any issue running MaintenanceSolution.sql script on a production database?

Comment: Many do, and I've never heard of any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild/Reorganize working fine. you are reading your query result incorrect.

**dm_db_index_physical_stats** fincation have index_id which display heap and index informatiob.

```
   indexstats.index_id = 0 -- Heap or table
   indexstats.index_id > 0 -- Indexes
```

below line will remove the `NULL` value from the query.

```
--and indexstats.index_id > 0

    SELECT     dbschemas.[Name] AS 'Schema',
    dbtables.[Name] AS 'Table',
    dbindexes.[Name] AS 'Index',
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.TABLES dbtables
    ON dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas
    ON dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes
    ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
and indexstats.index_id > 0
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```